# Unable to receive emails from Ubuntu postfix mail server

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I am unable to receive emails on an Ubuntu 11.04 server running postfix with the Plesk control panel. I can't see the mails even on webmail. I am able to send emails and am not getting any error messages on the email client when I try to receive. Here is the output of the logs:

***tail -f /usr/local/psa/var/log/maillog**

Aug 29 10:38:31 cp9 postfix/tlsmgr[3811]: fatal: open database

/var/lib/postfix/smtpd_scache.db: Invalid argument

Aug 29 10:38:32 cp9 postfix/master[27738]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/tlsmgr pid 3811 exit status 1

Aug 29 10:38:32 cp9 postfix/master[27738]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/tlsmgr: bad command startup -- throttling

Aug 29 10:38:36 cp9 pop3d: Connection, ip=[::ffff:196.201.x.x]

Aug 29 10:38:36 cp9 pop3d: IMAP connect from @ [::ffff:196.201.x.x]INFO: LOGIN, user=earle@essentialhuku.co.za, ip=[::ffff:196.201.x.x]

Aug 29 10:38:37 cp9 pop3d: 1346229517.874008 LOGOUT, user=earle@essentialhuku.co.za, ip=[::ffff:196.201.x.x], top=0, retr=0, time=1, rcvd=24, sent=1716, maildir=/var/qmail/mailnames/essentialhuku.co.za/earle/Maildir

Aug 29 10:14:05 cp9 postfix/tlsmgr[1133]: fatal: open database /var/lib/postfix/smtpd_scache.db: Invalid argument

Aug 29 10:14:06 cp9 postfix/master[27738]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/tlsmgr pid 1133 exit status 1

Aug 29 10:14:06 cp9 postfix/master[27738]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/tlsmgr: bad command startup -- throttling

Aug 29 10:14:08 cp9 pop3d: Connection, ip=[::ffff:196.201.x.x

Comment: Just when users started complaining, I saw the machine was out of disk space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Plesk or ISPConfig?

Try `rm /var/lib/postfix/smtpd_scache.db`

I got this solution by Googling `invalid argument sltn postfix`. You omitted `sltn` from this post.

You should add that the problem started when the disk space ran out.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by mv /var/lib/postfix/smtpd_scache.db rm /var/lib/postfix/smtpd_scache.db.backup. It seem the smtpd_scache.db was the cause of the problem. I got the advise from http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=50569